# Help swapping out one player character for another

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

recently I’ve been working on a system that would allow the player to swap out one character for another with a touch of a button.

So far I’ve just been trying to focus on switching to one character in particular before expanding into being able to switch to all the other characters.

***Player Controller blueprint - Character swapping setup:***
[image]

***Character blueprint:***
[image]

I’ve managed to set up the blueprint so that when the character being controlled by the player pushes the right analog stick to the left, the previous actor is destroyed and the new character is spawned in their place. I’ve also managed to accomplish switching my custom camera from following the old character to the new one as well.

However, the one thing I haven’t been able to accomplish is that the newly spawned character won’t respond to any controller input. Not only is the character unable to move but they can’t access the pause menu as well, which would appear to indicate that the Player Controller blueprint isn’t taking control of the new character when they spawn into the level.

I’m not sure why is happening, which is why I need help in figuring out why it isn’t working properly.

I was also wondering if anyone also knows how I can spawn the new character in the exact same location as the old one.

[image]

With my current setup, the newly spawned character appears at the start of the level instead of the exact same location as the previously spawned character.

As always, any help whatsoever with either of these issues would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
I’ve managed to get the new character to spawn in the same spot as the previous one, as well as getting them to face in the same direction upon spawning.

[image]

Unfortunately though, I'm still unable to get the Player Controller blueprint to possess the newly spawned character when I switch characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I managed to solve the problem myself.  It turns out the solution was to remove the Set Actor Tick Enabled node, as once it was removed my character swapping setup started to work properly.

[image]